# Best way to serialize a JOIN SQL query to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter, join

I can't find a good title for my question. I'm doing a Restful API /JSON

My problem is:

I have got two tables:

```
Product: id, name
Prices: id_product, price

Product 1--* Prices (One product have got multiples prices)
```

So, If I want to export the next information in JSON

```
products: [
     {
          id:1
          name: chair
          prices: [3.3,5.0,6.0]
     }
      , {
          id:2
          name: apple
          prices: [2.0,5.0]
     } ,..
]
```

I do the next query:

```
SELECT product.id, product.name, prices.price FROM procut LEFT JOIN prices ON product.id = prices.id_product
```

I got the next result:

```
id  , name  , prices
----------------------
 1    chair    3.3
 1    chair    5.0
 1    chair    6.0
 2    apple    ...
...
```

I use PHP, codeigniter. Is there a way to transform in a well form JSON? Because I have to rebuild the result, doing:

```
        $resultArray = $query->result_array();  //CodeIgniter

        foreach($resultArray as $row)
        {
            if(!isset($resultData[$row['id']]))
            {
                $resultData[$row['id']] = $row;
                unset($resultData[$row['id']]['price']);

                $resultData[$row['id']]['prices'] = array();

            }

            $resultData[$row['id']]['prices'][] = $row['price'];
        }
```

to create the JSON well formed

Comment: don't know what you mean ?
take your array and write something like `$this->output
   ->set_content_type('application/json')
   ->set_output(json_encode($resultData));`

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but I will output five objets Json (in this particular case) because each row will be a object json. And I only have two (in my example) so for that I have to build my objecy json before output in json encode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a normal practice to sort result from SQL with PHP, so You're on the right way.

```
    $result = array();
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
        $result[$row['id']] = array(
            'id'=>$row['id'],
            'name'=>$row['name'],
            'price'=>isset($result[$row['id']]['price']) ? array_push($result[$row['id']]['price'],$row['price']) : array($row['price'])
        );
    }

    $this->output
                ->set_content_type('application/json')
                ->set_output(json_encode(array('products'=>array_values($result))));
```

Comment: Okey. Thanks. I thoght I was doing a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: @jlmg5564 no problem. Don't forget to mark answer as solution if You agree with it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way (assuming you have multiple lines in your prices table). I find it cleaner doing like this in comparison to the way you were doing it. This can be a method in your model class

```
$this->db->select("id, name");
$this->db->from("product");
$q = $this->db->get();
$products = $q->result();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $this->db->select("price");
    $this->db->from("prices");
    $this->db->where("id_product", $product->id);
    $q = $this->db->get();
    $product->prices = $q->result();
}

$json = json_encode($products);
var_dump($json);
```

Comment: So... If you have 1000 products,  yo do 1000 querys.  Maybe more clear but very inefficient